# disable NSTableView double click

Tags: cocoa

I hope to disable NSTableView row double click and forbid row item edit.

Is it possible to disable NSTableView row double click?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try including this method and return NO:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(int)rowIndex {
    return NO;
}
```

Also check out the documentation for [`NSTableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use Tableview delegate method
   `tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row
2. Or you can also disable this from Interface builder
3. or you can also overwrite mouse click event of tableview

.